# Is there a way to take First() from a hierarchy table in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there any way to access a table that is a hierarchy?

Entity Framework Core returns null from the `First()` method, the table is NOT empty. I use SQL Server to store the table.

```
public class TestProjectEFDbContext : DbContext
{
    private const string connectionString = @"data source=DESKTOP-I2JBLKP; Initial Catalog=TestProjectEF;  Trusted_Connection=True; ";

    public TestProjectEFDbContext() { }
    public TestProjectEFDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<University> Universities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MedicineUniversity> MedicineUniversities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArtUniversity> ArtUniversities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TechUniveristy> TechUniveristies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
} 

var FirstUniversity = testProjectEFDbContext.Universities.First(); // throws an error
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: THE SEQUENCE IS EMPTY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements` When appeared that you have not any records in the mapped table.

[image]

And it is disappeared when you use `FirstOrDefault()` extension method.

So, double-check the database and table that you are using in the connection string and you have checked that have records.

Also, beware of Table Attribute: `[Table(string name, Properties:[Schema = string])`

Comment: you have a serious problem in your model, I fixed that and uploading the content. just give me a few minutes.

Comment: Give me access to your repository plz; my github Id is : xaamt

Comment: Unfortunately; I still have a permission problem, so I forked your repository and change it for myself. you can get it from https://github.com/xaamt/Stack